# How can I disable a page from an application in Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I don´t want to delete it, I just want to disable.

[image: I don't know where is the option for that]

Comment: What does "deactivate" mean?

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you want the page to be displayed but in read-only mode? Or do you want it hidden?

Answer (score 1):

If "disabling" means that you'd want to keep that page in your application (because you think it is simply beautiful and don't want to delete it) but don't let anyone use it, you could:

- in shared components, go to "Authorization schemes"
- create a new scheme, let's call it "AS_disabled"
- set its type to "PL/SQL Function returning Boolean"
- put `return 1 = 2;` into the function body (as it is never equal, the function will return false)
- put "This page is disabled" into the message property
- now, navigate to Page 4
- edit its Authorization scheme property and set it to "AS_disabled"
- save & run the page - you shouldn't be able to do it

Alternatively, if you want to have it accessible only to you, instead of `1 = 2` you could use `return :APP_USER = 'JAPH_SXAS';` (or whichever username you use in Apex). Everyone else will receive the "This page is disabled" message.